# Google Analytics: Adding a metric returns different result

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm working on a Google Analytics data extraction and I realized a difference in the results when I add a metric.

When I query the API like this `https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxx&start-date=2018-12-01&end-date=2018-12-31&metrics=ga:totalEvents&dimensions=ga:eventLabel,ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction&max-results=100&start-index=1&filters=ga:eventLabel=~théories et pratiques de l'enseignement programmé: guide à l'usage des enseignants`
 I receive this:

```
"totalsForAllResults": {
    "ga:totalEvents": "23"
  }
```

When I add `ga:dateHourMinute` to the metrics, the same property returns `14` instead of `23`. Is there a way for me the get the right totalEvents, in this case it's 23, and also get the date and time in the same query?

Comment: In the response of your second query, the parameter containsSampledData is true or false?

Comment: @MichelePisani when it return 23 the sample data is false, when it return 14 it is true

Comment: @MichelePisani I tried with samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION  and the result is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments we understand that you have reached the **sampling threshold**. Default reports are not subject to sampling. However, by applying a secondary dimension (in this case `ga:dateHourMinute`), you required an ad-hoc queries so your data are subject to the thresholds for sampling, see here:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en

What you can do is query two shorter periods and then add the values of events ​​together.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I don't understand much of Google Analytics but most of the issues I've been reading is about data sampling. I'll try querying day by day instead of month.